# Would implicit operators make DTOs smelly?

Tags: automapper, dto

The project I'm working on has:

```
public class MyObjectDTO
{
    public string Lorem { get; set; }
    public string Ipsum { get; set; }
    public string Dolor { get; set; }
}
public class MyObjectSummaryDTO
{
    public string Lipsum { get; set; }
}
```

I have a map from MyObjectDTO to MyObjectSummaryDTO.

Depending on `Dolor`, the value in`MyObjectSummaryDTO.Lipsum` should be `Lorem` or `Ipsum`.

Does adding an implicit operator on one of the DTOs break the pattern of DTOs? Can I extend AutoMapper to include this logic? I don't want to add yet another layer just to get a facade from an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't want to hide this functionality inside of your automapper configuration. I guarentee at some point in the future another programmer will be extremely confused by this suddenly changing value.

Instead, provide a GetLipsum() function that contains the business logic for determining which value to return. This way the flow of finding out where the value of Lipsum comes from still resides in the execution path of the program.

Generally I would speak in ViewModel and Model terms here, but I'm not sure if your summary is a ViewModel or not. Either way, the business logic should reside in your model layer.

```csharp
public class MyObjectDTO
{
    public string Lorem { get; set; }
    public string Ipsum { get; set; }
    public string Dolor { get; set; }
    public string GetLipsum() { //Automapper smartly maps this automatically to Lipsum
         return Dolor == "Amet" ? "Lorem" : "Ipsum";
    }
}
public class MyObjectSummaryDTO
{
    public string Lipsum { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this put business logic into the DTO, which should stay dumb?

Comment: I could only construct example code from the available models, but I did write in my answer that this business logic should reside in your model layer. You might decide to move the GetLipsum() 'down' a level and only provide a Lipsum property which has been mapped up to your DTO level.